# How to change a table row value to another table row value in postgresql

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I have database in postgresql which have a schema inside which i have many tables. i have a specific table that i want. this table contain many fields, in which there is a field named user1_id. this field contains numbers. there are 4 users. The user1_id field goes like given below:

```
user1_id
--------
   1
   1
   2
   4
   3
   4
   .
   .
 Goes-on
```

this user1_id is a primary key in another table in the same schema. and the name of this field is named "id" in the other table. This id field represents a field named "username" which is the name of the users. The username field is given below:

```
id  username
--  --------
1     alan
2     ali
3     joe
4     aadhi
```

as i mentioned earlier there are 4 users and these are the names.
now i want to replace the user1_id to the username rows according to the 'id'.
ie, if 1 = alan, i want 'alan' to appear in the first table whenever 1 shows up in "user1_id". how can i do it in postgresql? or as a sql statement in python?

Comment: Have you tried a simple update statement like this `UPDATE first_table
SET user1_id = second_table.username
FROM second_table
WHERE first_table.user1_id = second_table.id;` ?\

Comment: Why not make a `FOREIGN KEY` reference from the table `user1_id` to the table with `id` where there reference is `user1_id` --> `id`? Then when add/change/delete users that is automatically 'seen' by the child table.

Answer (score 1):

A basic join should suffice here:

```sql
SELECT t1.user1_id, t2.username
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON t2.id = t1.user1_id;
```

To populate a new text column `new_column` in the first table with the `username` values from the second table, we can do an update join:

```sql
UPDATE table1 t1
SET new_column = t2.username
FROM table2 t2
WHERE t2.id = t1.user1_id;
```

Comment: It works fine but i want to replace the values in "user1_id" to "usernames" value as per the id numbers

Comment: @Lukman Check the updated answer for an update join option.

Comment: ERROR:  column "user1_id" is of type integer but expression is of type character varying   I am getting this error

Comment: I only gave you what you asked for.  You should create a new text column and then update it.